# Loading Denormalized Data Into A Database

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, csv

I have a database (postgres) with two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE invoices (
    id bigint,
    some_data varchar
)

CREATE TABLE charges (
    id bigint,
    invoice_id bigint,
    some_data varchar
)
```

I'm trying to load a csv file with the following format into this database:

```
invoice_id, invoice_data, charge_id, charge_data
```

For example, I could have the following lines in my csv file:

```
1, $10.00, 1, $2.00
1, $10.00, 2, $5.00
1, $10.00, 3, $3.00
2, $2.00,  4, $1.00
2, $2.00,  5, $1.00
3, $11.00, 6, $11.00
```

This data should correspond to the following records in the database:

```
SELECT * FROM invoices;
  id | some_data
-----+-------------
  1  | $10.00
  2  | $2.00
  3  | $11.00

SELECT * FROM charges;
  id | invoice_id | some_data
-----+------------+-------------
  1  | 1          | $2.00
  2  | 1          | $5.00
  3  | 1          | $3.00
  4  | 2          | $1.00
  5  | 2          | $1.00
  6  | 3          | $11.00
```

Is there a 'best practices' for loading this kind of data? At the moment, I am loading this file into an intermediary table and processing it with a php script (bad). It's quite inefficient. Is there a better way? Should I be loading this into an intermediary table and then using a stored procedure to split up the information? Or should I be processing my .csv file directly and splitting this information in some sort of script?

Comment: Loading into a staging table first (using COPY), then using plain SQL to distribute the data to the two destination tables is a common way of loading and massaging data.

Comment: Should I create a stored procedure for this? Or just keep the sql somewhere with the file loading script?

Comment: A db function (in Postgres they are functions, not stored procedures) is a simple way to encapsulate the logic of moving the data from one table to the others so yeah that works just fine. If the columns and tables change regularly, it might make more sense to keep plain SQL in your loading script, but if it is reasonably static I would be inclined to go the function route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the COPY command to load the data first into a intermediary table whose structure matches the CSV (for example: COPY intermediary_table FROM '/path/to/csv/charges.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;), then select the data into each table. The first query would be a SELECT DISTINCT invoice_id, invoice_data INTO invoices FROM intermediary_table, the second query SELECT DISTINCT charge_id, invoice_id, charge_data INTO charges FROM intermediary_table.

BTW, you most likely do not need to use bigint (unless you expect billions of rows).